# Get input file from another view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, razor

We use `Razor` with `MVC` and `AngularJs`.

I have a form where you can select an image from a . From there you can select to upload the image with a submit button or you can go to a new view to add more info about the image and then upload it.

My issue is how can I send along the selected image in the  to the new view, add my extra data and *then* upload the image?

**This is part of view #1:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UploadStuff", "someController", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })){
    //This will send you to the addMoreInfo view and not upload the file
    <input type="button" ui-sref="someController.addMoreInfo" value="Add more info" />
    //This will upload the selected file to the server
    <input type="submit" value="Save and close" />
}
```

**The controller:**
This will take care of the saving of the selected file and works fine on submit.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UploadStuff(HttpPostedFileBase imageUpload)
{
    if (imageUpload != null)
    {
        if (imageUpload.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            string filePath = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/Content/upload"),
                Path.GetFileName(imageUpload.FileName));
            imageUpload.SaveAs(filePath);
            return RedirectToAction("toSomeView", "someController");
        }
    }
    return View();
}
```

**View #2 - The addMoreInfo view:**

```
<h2>Add more info</h2>
Title:<br/>
<input type="text"/><br/>
<input type="button" value="Save"/>
```

Don't worry about the moreInfo part. I am just interested in how I get hold of the selected file from view #1 and save it by pushing the save button in view #2. Should I maybe add a BeginForm here as well and post to the server? But then I would need the seleced file from view #1 ;) I know there is not much Angular code in my example, but we use that as well and if you have some tricks up your sleeve with angular fixing this issue; go ahead. But I guess this is fixed with Razor. Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Razor is a server-side thing.  Angular is a client-side thing.  So, the question is ... does pressing the "Add more info" button make a server roundtrip?  It would be unnecessary for it to do so, in which case, your solution should be based in Angular.

So, I think you ought to create a new Angular view and new Angular controller to represent your "Add more info" view.  To pass information from your original controller to the new controller, the recommended approach is to define an Angular service which can be injected into both controllers.  Search for "angular how to pass information from one controller to another" for more detail.